# How to serve content generated with html/template from an embedded filesystem correctly?

Tags: go, http, templates

When I visit `localhost:8080` on my browser, I get a page displaying the correct field values from the template, however, the css does not load properly. When I visit the Web Developer Tools panel on my browser I notice that there are two identical errors for the `.js` and the `.css` files, namely

```
The resource from “http://localhost:8080/static/style.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

(I'm only showing the error associated with the `.css` file, the other is identical)

I really don't know what else to do, as I've already tried all the simple solutions like modifying the relative paths or building the binary at the same level as `main.go` and running the server from there.

As far as I can tell, the embedding has worked for the `templates` folder however it seems it somehow doesn't work for the contents of the `static` folder. I think I'm not wrong to say that while the server loads the template successfully, it fails to locate the `/static/styles.css` (same for the `.js` file) when parsing the DOM (it can't find the /static/ folder).

At this point, anybody's guess is as good as mine.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't the server route the `\static\` folder successfully? Is there something else wrong with my code?

Honestly, I'm seeing gibberish at this point. Any help is welcome. Thanks

### My code

My folder structure is the following

```
static
    |
    script.js
    styles.css
templates
    |
    template.html
handler.go
main.go
```

This is my `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

//go:embed static templates
var content embed.FS

func main() {
    // Define the handler function for the page to display
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)

    // Serve the static files (CSS, JS, images) from the "static" directory
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.FS(content))))

    // Start the server on port 8080
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

This is my `handler.go` file:

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    /* other imports */
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Define the template data
    data, err := /* code that returns data for the template */
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // I wasn't sure how to handle this
    }

    // Parse the template file
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFS(content, "templates/template.html")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // Execute the template with the data
    err = tmpl.Execute(w, data)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}
```

This is my `template.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Countdown</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    /* here is code accessing the fields of the data passed to the template */
    <script src="/static/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't present the `script.js` file because it's empty for the time being and because the problem it causes is identical to that of the `style.css`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` isn't the root of your filesystem, so `http.StripPrefix` isn't necessary.

With it, a request to `/static/some-file.js` looks for `/some-file.js` in the filesystem. Without it, the `/static/` is kept, which is how your filesystem is actually laid out.

So, you want:

```golang
// Serve the static files (CSS, JS, images) from the "static" directory
http.Handle("/static/", http.FileServer(http.FS(content)))
```

Comment: the fog of code, man; I actually had it figured out the other way around; I was trying every permutation of the code I could think of, but you can't successfully rearrange pieces that don't fit together, in the first place; it's embarrassing but I thought that `http.StripPrefix` was supposed to strip everything *before* `static` so as to get a clean route to `/static/whatever.xyz` instead of eg `http://whatever.com/static/something.com`